# How to make a certain View in MVC not inherit _Layout.cshtml?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, view, master-pages

I'm using ASP.NET MVC5, razor syntax.  I need a specific *"Create"* view to NOT inherit the `_Layout.cshtml` Shared View.

Basically, in this particular View, I don't want any of the `_Layout.cshtml` features like the navigation menu, footer, etc.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use.

```
@{
    Layout = null
}
```

In whatever `.cshtml` file you don't want to inherit the `_layout.cshtml`

Comment: In any View page (cshtml) you set it as you would normally set your view

Answer (score 2):

It inherits Layout because of your `_ViewStart.cshtml` file. Look at your ViewStart and delete related line. Then if you want to use Layout in your page you have to specify your Layout in each page.

Comment: I agree this is an approach, but doing this will require me to add the layout manually to every view I want to inherit the layout.. this would be good if I had maybe 1 or 2 views that needed the layout, but for me, it's the opposite, I only need 1 view to not have the layout, so `Layout = null` seems like the best approach for me.